# SSMS 2016 error "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm"

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2016

I am trying to connect a database from SSMS 2016 it gets connected from one machine but other machine with exactly same version SSMS 2016 gives below mentioned issue.

Note: on server only TLS > 1.2 protocols active and it is hosted using Microsoft SQL Server 2012

But if it works on one machine it should be working on other too ( if we are using same version of SSMS 2016).

Not sure what is missing on another machine.
[image]

Comment: TLS settings are not dependant on SSMS but rather on OS. If one machine has TLS1.2 enabled and the other does not then it will not work even with same SSMS version.

Comment: Which version of Windows is your machine? Have you enabled TLS1.2 on it if necessary?